# Как сбросить изменения в QSqlRelationalTableModel?

Tags: c++, qt

дано: две связанные таблицы
первая.

```
CRMModel::CRMModel(QObject *parent, QSqlDatabase db)
    : QSqlRelationalTableModel(parent, db)
{

    setTable("orders");
    setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel::LeftJoin);
    setRelation(fieldIndex("worker_id"),QSqlRelation("workers","worker_id","name"));
    select();
}
```

вторая

```
workersModel =  new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this,baze);
    workersModel->setTable("workers");
    workersModel->setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
    workersModel->select();

    ui->workersTableView->setModel(workersModel);
    ui->workersTableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->workersTableView->hideColumn(0);
```

кнопка добавления новой записи

```
void MainWindow::on_addOrderButton_clicked()
{
    const int row = model->rowCount();
    qDebug() << "inserting row" <<  model->insertRow(row);
    new_o->mapper->setCurrentModelIndex(model->index(row,0));
    new_o->show();
}
```

ну и mapper

```
void newOrder::setModel(QSqlRelationalTableModel *model)
{

    mapper->setModel(model);

    mapper->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(this));

    mapper->addMapping(ui->adressLineEdit,1);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->orderTextEdit,2,"plainText");
    mapper->addMapping(ui->phoneLineEdit,3);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->phone2lineEdit,4);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->execDateEdit,6);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->timeEdit,7);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->timeEdit2,8);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->spinBox,9);
    mapper->addMapping(ui->workerComboBox,10);


    QSqlTableModel *relModel = model->relationModel(10);
    ui->workerComboBox->setModel(relModel);
    ui->workerComboBox->setModelColumn(relModel->fieldIndex("name"));
}

void newOrder::on_applyButton_clicked()
{

    mapper->submit();
    emit ready();
    close();

}

void newOrder::on_closeButton_clicked()
{
    emit signalCancelOrder();
    close();
}
```

сигналы добавления и отмена записи

```
connect(new_o,SIGNAL(ready()),this,SLOT(orderAccepted()));
connect(new_o,SIGNAL(signalCancelOrder()),this,SLOT(orderCancled()));
```

слоты

```
void MainWindow::orderAccepted()
{

    qDebug() << "adding new order" << model->submitAll();

}

void MainWindow::orderCancled()
{
    qDebug() << "cancel" << model->submitAll();
}
```

Почему не работает слот orderCancled()????
При нажатии кнопки on_addOrderButton_clicked() добавляется сразу же пустая строка в таблицу.Как ее сбросить при отмене?? на submitAll ругается!

Comment: Так [`revertAll()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#revertAll), вроде.

Comment: спасиб. А еще такой вопрос если я в таблицу(делегат) добавляю новые данные они появляются только после перезапуска программы. Что мне сделать чтобы в главной модели(model) я их сразу увидел? Надо обновить все модели или как?

Comment: Для обновления модели данными из БД используется `select()`.